# Removing an object from array of arraylist<String>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a array of ArrayList as defined below.

```
List<ArrayList<String>> reverseRange = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

and I set it to:

```
[[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]]
```

by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < naive.size(); i++) { reverseRange.add(A); }
```

where A = [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]

I want to delete an object from specific list. Like:

```
reverseRange.get(0).remove("a");
```

but when I do that, it removes "a" from all lists and the result becomes:

```
[[b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i], [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How did you fill this *array*? It looks like it contains same list instance multiple times, instead of having multiple list instances with same characters.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < naive.size(); i++) {
   reverseRange.add(A);
  }

where A = [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]

Comment: That confirms it. You are adding *same* instance of list from `A` reference to `reverseRange` list multiple times. Try with `for (int i = 0; i < naive.size(); i++) { reverseRange.add(new ArrayList<>(A)); }` which in each iteration will create separate instance of `ArrayList`, fill it with elements from `A`, and then place it in `reverseRange`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you. Seems like I was only referencing to A multiple times

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Maybe the questions have strong connection to eachother, they are asking essentially different things. Closing this question was a bad thing.